# How to fix do not use BuildContexts across async gaps across over async function with provider

Tags: flutter

I am using provider and want to use `context` when calling two `async` function. But **Flutter lint** show warning as **Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps**. How can I fix it?

This is my code

```
Future<void> selectStartDateTime(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime? date = await selectStartDate(context);
    if (date == null) return;
    
    /// Here show warning 

    TimeOfDay? time = await selectStartTime(context);
    if (time == null) return;

    DateTime dateTime =
        DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day, time.hour, time.minute);

    selectedStartDate = DateFormat('d-MMM-yyyy h:mm a').format(dateTime);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Be sure to check mounted and return immediately if no longer mounted before any use of context.

Comment: Just add if(mounted) return; before TimeOfDay? time = await selectStartTime(contex);

Comment: I write this method as service, not in ```Stateless``` nor ```Stateful``` widget. So how can I check?

Comment: If add ```if(mounted)return```. Get can't identify ```mounted``` error. @MoïseRajesearison

Answer (score 0):

In recent Flutter versions (>3.7.0) you can reach the `mounted` variable from the context. So you can do `context.mounted` and then check on that.

Comment: This is my flutter version
**Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.0, on macOS 13.2 22D49 darwin-x64, locale en-US)** and even I can't add ```context.mounted```.

Comment: Update to at least 3.7.0